# In OpenAPI 3 Make Servers a text box

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

In OpenAPI 3, what changes would I have to make in the yaml so that the dropdown of Servers in the swagger yaml is instead a text box where devs can put in their own ApiPaths for testing their own deployments.

[image: Servers Drop-down]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the Server Templating section in https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/ does just this.

```
servers:
  - url: https://{customerId}.saas-app.com:{port}/v2
    variables:
      customerId:
        default: demo
        description: Customer ID assigned by the service provider
      port:
        enum:
          - '443'
          - '8443'
        default: '443'
```

In this case `customerId` will show up as a text box in the swagger.